# Option to select a range and fixed values

Tags: input, sliders, range, value

Im currently designing the UI for a event tool.

When the user is creating an event he has the option to select the amount of people needed for this event.

He should be able to define a range (e.g. "i need between 5 and 8 people") and fixed values like "i need a minimum of 4 people", "i need a maximum of 8 people"

Im not sure whats the best way to display this so the users is not getting completely confused what to select.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to define a range/scope - You can:

- Use slider

[image]

- Use 2 inputs [begin - end]
  [image]

For values:

- Min 4 people
- Min 300 €

It's good practise to define in logic of those solution or add additional radio buttons.

Comment: Thank you, i will use the 2 input field version for now, i think this will do well in testing.

Comment: and easier for implementing :)